# Running individual views/controllers in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

**Question**

Is there a way to run a single UIViewController so that I may see the resulting view without having to run the entire application?

**Background**

I'm working in a codebase that isn't using many xib files; the views are generated programmatically in a lot of places. To view my modifications I'm having to run the application and step through it to reach the desired view I just changed and it can be a bit cumbersome. Some times I'll hardcode it to some early point in the applications flow just so I can see what it looks like when its ran. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a story board and your view controllers in it?

Comment: @GurtejSingh No story boards

Comment: Ok, if your UIViewControllers can run independently, can you change your `rootViewController` in your AppDelegate class to load a different UIViewController at startup?

Comment: @GurtejSingh That's essentially what I do. I don't change the AppDelegate but I will insert the class I want to test as one of the early main menu controllers. I was hoping there was an xcode method of building a specific UIViewController then running just that file in a modular fashion so I don't have to go back into the code and revert the changes I've made to the rootViewController etc

Comment: Well in storyboard we do have a 'is initial view controller' which allows me to easily switch, but you are right about the struggle of changing it through code. Upvoting your question so that we can find a better answer :)

Comment: @GurtejSingh Thanks. I realize this is a problem in other areas like web application development if your view is not just an html page and dependent on dynamic ruby or java generated content and I basically do the exact same thing. If there's no better approach perhaps its worth me trying to write my own plug in for xcode or something...

Comment: Great question, and one that the iOS community has no great answer for. It's a travesty that it's not possible to run a specific view. I end up creating new targets that act as mini-apps for each view controller, believe it or not!

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way would be as  @Gurtej Singh suggested, 
but to make it a bit easier for beginners to Xcode
you need to move the the "little arrow" pointing to right direction next to 
the default storyboard scene (it's the first storyboard you get when you create a fresh project) 
check the picture below of a storyboard and the inspecter 
just drag-drop the arrow to the storyboard you want to test/run

[image]